# Type '(string | number)' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: typescript

please help with a problem. I want to create a function than get an array in parameters that contains numbers and strings, and return an array of numbers.

```
function numArray(array:  (string | number)[]): number[] {
  const resArray: number[] = array.filter((el): boolean => typeof(el) === 'number');
  return resArray;
}
```

TS throw an Error:

```
ERROR in src/App.tsx:16:9
TS2322: Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
  Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    14 |     }
    15 |   }
  > 16 |   const resArray: number[] = array.filter((el): boolean => typeof(el) === 'number');
       |         ^^^^^^^^
    17 |   return resArray;
    18 | }
```

I understand that source array is (number | string) and may we can not create an array of numbers from it, but resArray consists just numbers and function return an array of numbers. May be this is a mechanic of TS...

Comment: `(el): boolean` -> `(el): el is number`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a User-Defined type guard on the `.filter` to let the compiler know your filter is only returning values that are numbers. You could tweak your function by doing the following:

```
function numArray(array:  (string | number)[]): number[] {
  const resArray = array.filter((el): el is number => typeof(el) === 'number');

  return resArray;
}
```

Comment: Omg... u are the best))